# Historical costs of nuclear magnetic resonance experiments

Tags: history

I was wondering how the **cost of magnetic resonance experiments** have changed over time. Not too long ago they didn't exist, now there are whole centres that do nothing else. Does this mean they're significantly **cheaper than they were?** If so, **how much?** I'm looking for some **quantitative data** on this.

It's quite easy to find purchase costs for machines, but an intuitive understanding of the history magnetic resonance technology would be easier with the pricing to be in terms of the costs of the information they produce.

Of course there will be different kinds of experiment that would take more or less time, require more or less resolution, field strength, RC equipment etc. So, perhaps it would make most sense talk about how much it costs to get information of a certain kind e.g. such as a proton spectrum for suitable for identifying small molecules, or, a single MRI image of a brain.

In summary, I'm looking for something [like this chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing#/media/File:Historic_cost_of_sequencing_a_human_genome.svg) for DNA sequencing, but for magnetic resonance. It plots which the costs of 1 genome (I'm guessing, for the chart = some fixed number of bases) against time. It's obviously much harder to do this for magnetic resonance experiments where there's not this kind of "cost per bit" analysis.

Does someone know where I can find this kind of data? Perhaps it's just a matter of making machine costs comparable?

Comment: It sounds like a research project in itself!  First you would need to determine a relevant measure (which requires research), then see what the costs were over time (more research), and then write it up.  But first: why does this matter? Who is the audience for this research?  If you know the answers to these final questions, then you would be able to discover if the questions have been addressed.  Try (a) the trade literature for NMR/MRI, and (b) check with an active researcher with a very long history in the field ...

Comment: I'd suggest  Economics.Stackexchange.  This is pretty much part of Econ101: development costs are high; after recouping (and with the onset of competition), mass production reduces costs.

Comment: In the spirit in which we say that questions about cost-trade-offs of design choices are off topic (as engineering), I think that this is as well. Whether it should go to engineering or economics (or indeed nowhere) is not clear to me.

Comment: The original machines were developed in laboratories, rather than being bought. The technique actually doesn't require that much stuff, and much of it would have been lying around in various labs. Now, they were also pretty crude. I know people who have built similar machines in their garage for fun. Purchased machine costs really should also (somehow) take into account any number of factors such as precision, sample size, operating cost reductions, etc.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I didn't know that existed, that does sound more appropriate.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Sure. I was kind of hoping that, along the lines of (b), there might be some MR experts who would know where to look, or how to make the question easier to answer. Expert input would make answering the question much easier. For example, they might have had to justify the running costs to their department, or, perhaps they've read around the topic enough to know where some esoterically conceived but relevant data is.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'd like to get my hands on some data. Anyone can predict that they would have got cheaper, but I would like to know empirically, and by how much.

Comment: @dmckee I think it belongs in history of science (a lot of historical research concerns the price of things)